# Gridster extra columns requirement

Tags: gridster, dashing

I have set up "dashing" to run on a raspberry pi, but i am having trouble with the display.
When i start it up and go to the local host, I can only seem to display 5 columns wide.
I have looked into the Gridster script, but I really do not know where to look.
We will be using a large widescreen display for this information so please can you advise how I can increase the column count or allow Chrome to display the full width on re-sizing.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your .erb and control the size of widgets and num columns. Have  a look at  sampletv.erb for the same code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function() {
    Dashing.widget_base_dimensions = [370, 340]
    Dashing.numColumns = 5
  });
</script>
```